# Execute javascript function in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

I'm doing auth with facebook that opens new tab and redirects user to backend on port 8080 after he is authenticated. Then he gets redirected back to app. From there I want to close the window and call function on opener window `window.opener.functionAfterFinish()` that will let it know auth finished. Problem is that I have to have that function in index.html for it to work. If I create `functionAfterFinish(): void{...}` in component, it won't get called.

What are my options ? How should I put that function in component and get it executed ?

Comment: Question is not clear to convey issue but you may try Facebook SDK angular wrapper named [ngx-facebook](https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook) instance of hardcoding javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll suggest you to use cookies.

1. Firstly, You need to create cookies while redirecting to the new tab.
   For Example : `this._cookieService.createCookie('fbCookies', 'success', 3);`
2. Now, you need to check the cookies by using a set interval in the method where you'are getting the authentication response.
   Example-

   ```
       let interval = setInterval(function(){
                        let cookie = this._cookieService.readCookie('fbCookies');
                        if (cookie === 'success') {
                            newWindow.close();
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }else if (cookie === null) {
                              clearInterval(interval);
                              newWindow.close();
                        }
                    }, 5000);
   ```

Thus, as soon as you'll get the success tab will be close.

Comment: I know about that, but that's not a good solution. Callback function is what I'm going for, but I can't figure out how to access functions in components. I was only able to access functions in index.html <script> tag.

Comment: "but I can't figure out how to access functions in components ", what exactly you want to say?  Can you explain a bit or post your code here so I can assist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your component service or method on the `window` object

Inside your service/component :

```
askFacebook(){
  (window as any).functionAfterFinish=this.functionAfterFinish.bind(this);
  // Do ask facebook
}
```

Be sure to run the callback in the angular zone.

(Sorry for brevity, i am answering on my phone. If you have questions, don't hesitate to post a comment)